# Youtube Data API - Search for video in a playlist

Tags: youtube

The YouTube API allows you to search for videos from a given channel by specifying the channel id - but is it possible to search for videos from a given playlist?

Currently I have set up using the API to get all videos from a chosen playlist

```
var request = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key={{my_key}}&part=contentDetails,snippet&playlist_id={{playlist_id}}&maxResults=6';
```

But I cant seem to combine search - unless I get all items from the playlist and then do a search on my end. Which would be inefficient and use more of my daily allowance.